# How can I fill select2 data dynamically using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2

My case is that I want to use the createSearchChoice feature of the Select2 widget. So I found out I need to use an html input element instead of a select element and so I cannot use ng-repeat to populate the select2 widget. I find out there is a 'data' option and have been able to populate the select2 widget with static data, but not when I've tried to fill it dynamically.

What works:

html:
  `<input class='select2' ui-select2='sel2props' type='hidden'>`

in the controller:

```
$scope.sel2props = {
    createSearchChoice: ...

  data: [ 
    { id: 0, text: 'yabba' }
    etc
  ]
};
```

But if I try to set data to a variable which I can then set to whatever the database feeds me the widget isn't populated.

```
data: $scope.data;

function to retrieve data {
    $scope.data = retrieved data;
}
```

the retrieved data is exactly in the way specified.

If i set up a button to append the data key it will work:

```
$scope.appenddata = function () {
  $scope.data.push({id:1, text: 'anot'});
};
```

So I'm thinking it's a timing issue and I try $digest and $apply but they don't work in controllers. I tried to set up a directive and actually can do simple widgets, but not select2, so I was hoping not to go down that path, well that is to say I went down that path and drowned. If anyone could help out that would be great.

Comment: What do you mean with "I try $digest and $apply but they don't work in controllers"? They work in any place that has access to the scope. Did you run it like this `$scope.$apply()`?

Comment: @ bmleite. Incorrect. you'll get an error: $apply already in progress within a controller.

Comment: That's because you're calling `$apply` on the wrong place. It has nothing to do with the controller. If you want a simple way to avoid the error, replace all calls to `$scope.$apply()` inside the controller with `$scope.$$phase || $scope.$apply()`. Note that this won't fix your problem, it will just avoid the error. Please provide a jsfiddle with your problem.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is straight forward. Just push the elements onto the select2 data array rather than referencing another array.

Comment: I had gone blind on this as well.. Reading your answer freed my mind; "YES off course!", why am I doing $scope.tags = [], 2 times...?

Answer (score 1):

```
function (result) {
  $scope.lookupOptions.data.length = 0; // remove old items
  angular.extend($scope.lookupOptions.data, result.data); // add new items                  
}
```

Answer (score -2):

A trick I've recently made use of is to use Select2's `query` option to pass in your latest data on demand.

I've put together an example, wrapped in a custom directive. See this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/q2ZJWedqGyCcDtIdvwWU?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks, but i want the user to add data hence the createSearchChoice option and the use of input instead of select. Also, your directive isn't handling the data very well: it includes an html span element for each option.

Comment: Do you want the data created by the user to be sent back to the database? Are you interested in a "multiple" select instead of a dropdown? I *am* using an `<input>` to create the select2 widget; select2 creates a dropdown like that when in single-select mode but that can easily change. Also, what do you mean I'm not "handling the data very well"? Select2 creates those HTML `<span>` elements in order to display the dropdown. I'll be happy to update my answer; I was only answering your immediate problem of dynamically adding data to Select2 when you retrieve data from your database.

Comment: the spans were showing in the dropdown when i first looked at your plunk, but they aren't now. so i don't know what that was about. The solution to mine was to push on each element to the data array rather than referencing another array.